# An SSL Error occurred when using pyscript request module

Tags: python, html, python-requests, github-pages, pyscript

I wanted to use a group bot to send messages in an app, and it was easy to be done when I was running the code in IDEs. However, when I was trying to use Pyscript and Github pages to run the code, it threw an SSL error.

```
<py-env>
 - requests
</py-env>
```

```
<py-script>
  import requests
  import json

  # Generated sign and timestamp
  
  def send_dingtalk_message(url, content):
      headers = {'wrote-headers'}
      data = {
           "msgtype": "text",
           "text": {
               # Message for the bot to send
               "content": content
           },
       }
      r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
      print(r.text)
      return r.text()

  def message(text):
      access_token = 'mainurl&timestamp=' + timestamp +'&sign=' + sign
      content = text
      # Send bot messages
      send_dingtalk_message(access_token, content)
      print("success")
  
  message("text")
</py-script>
```

And it threw an error

```
PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): (a lot of file names)..(Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I tried to use other ways to post the url, but it seems that nothing could be used to do so.

Comment: The `requests` module is not supported in the web browser. Browser-based applications cannot directly open TCP sockets. All network requests must use browser APIs. in summary, you are limited to the `fetch` API.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Pyodide limitation. Maybe try luck with XmlHttpRequest window.fetch JS API directly.